# Laravel, How to convert number to hours and minutes

Tags: php, laravel

How Can I convert number in controller to hours and minutes then to get requested variable to compare if its in the range between to times,
Im storing in the database just number of hour like:
22 which means 22:00:00
2 which means 02:00:00
and so on
hope you have a solution

Comment: I suggest you to use date time fields.

Comment: can you explain more please

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the amazing Carbon for this:

```
// import at the top of your class
use Carbon\Carbon;

Carbon::createFromFormat('H', 22)->format('H:i:s');

// => "22:00:00"
```

To use it for comparison, just use the first part without the format, but then when you create the date like this it will use the current date, I don't know what you want to compare? Is it just the hours or the date as well?

Comment: it returns empty

Comment: What returns empty? can you show what you are trying? Because I shared something that I already tested in my project.